# Application specific isolated CngKey

Tags: c#, windows, security, cryptography, cng

I am creating a [CngKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccng/cng-portal). The key is being generated successfully. The problem I am facing is that, I want to use concept of Sandboxing. Like in Android or iOS, one application cannot access the data of another application. I want the similar behavior in windows application. Here is my code to create a CngKey:

```
private CngKey generateKeyPair(string keyId)
    {
        CngKey key = null;
        if (CngKey.Exists(keyId, CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider, CngKeyOpenOptions.MachineKey))
        {
            key = CngKey.Open(keyId, CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider, CngKeyOpenOptions.MachineKey);

        }
        else
        {
            key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256, keyId, new CngKeyCreationParameters
            {
                ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.None,
                KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.MachineKey,
                KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.AllUsages,
                Provider = CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider,
                UIPolicy = new CngUIPolicy(CngUIProtectionLevels.None)
            });
        }
        return key
    }
```

Let's say this key is created by Application_A. But if Application_B knows the keyId, it can access the same key. I don't want this. I cannot use GenericRead access rule to restrict it:

```
new CryptoKeyAccessRule(
                    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NetworkServiceSid, null),
                    CryptoKeyRights.GenericRead,
                    AccessControlType.Allow)
```

Since I have to access it at various points in Application_A.

How can I achieve my goal? Am I using the right thing for my purpose?

Comment: Are you sure "Since I have to access it at various points in Application_A." is correct? Or do you  merely have to *use* the key at various points in the application?

Comment: Actually the application continuously runs in the background. Whenever a call is made to the app, it first fetches the key based on some parameters and then do further processing. This is what I actually meant by "I have to access it at various points in Application_A."

Comment: I don’t think CNG has any special isolation here, you’d need to be in a bigger isolation mode that virtuaized the filesystem paths to CNG’s key storage.